# What is the closure of a set A ? In complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that the definition of closure is :

$\overline {A}=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} :\forall \varepsilon >0,D_{\varepsilon }\left( z\right) \cap A\neq \emptyset\} $

Where A is a subset of the complex numbers.

From my understanding it means that the closure of A are those that are arbitrarily close to the points in A ?

But what does that actually mean, and from that what are its applications in complex analysis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what you say. Another equivalent definition of closure in $\mathbb{C}$ is:

A set $A$ is closed if every convergent sequence in $A$ has its limit inside $A$.

In fact, try to prove this as an exercise. Also, show that the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Edit: As for the usefulness of closures, it is not limited to complex analysis. There is a more general definition of closure in topology. The most important results are that continuous functions on a compact domain attain a minimum and maximum (and similar statements). A compact set is a set which automatically closed (unless you're working in non-Hausdorff topology, which most people don't).